# Can I download the blockchain blocks from torrent and paste them?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

Currently my Bitcoin Core client was stopped syncing at 40.73%.  It was not progressing any more.  I've downloaded the Blockchain from https://getbitcoinblockchain.com/ .  Can I just copy these blocks and paste these downloaded blocks to my Bitcoin > Blocks ?  Will everything be fine ?  Will the Bitcoin Core client accepts the downloaded blockchain ?

Comment: You can certainly download the blockchain and copy the blocks. Keep in mind though that the process of blockchain synchronization involves downloading and validating blocks. By downloading a torrent you are not validating the blocks so there may be additional risks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can download the blockchain from other sources then paste it inside the your main bitcoin folder.
You will need two folders:
- blocks
- chainstate
Then open bitcoin-qt for synchronization.

Comment: There's no point though as letting bitcoind do the downloading should be strictly faster and more efficient. If something's wrong there it might be better to fix the underlying problem.